How are residuals calculated in a logistic regression model?
I created a logistic regression model using the mlr3 package in R. I outputted residuals from the model, but I can't work out how they have been calculated - they do not correspond to any residual calculation that I know of.
Suppose I use the mlr3 package to create a logistic regression model:
library(mlr3)
library(tidyverse)

#create dummy data
data <- data.frame(
  predictor = c(rnorm(50, mean = 0), rnorm(50, mean = 1)),
  dependant = as.factor(c(rep(0,50), rep(1, 50)))
)

#define and train a logistic regression model
classifier_log_reg <-  mlr_learners$get("classif.log_reg")
task <- mlr3::TaskClassif$new(id = "my_data",
                                     backend = data,
                                     target = "dependant", # target variable
                                     positive = "1")
classifier_log_reg$train(task, row_ids = 1:100)

I can get the residuals from the model using:
residuals <- classifier_log_reg$model$residuals
My question is: how are these residuals calculated? I cannot reproduce them manually. They don't match the numbers I get when I calculate pearson or deviance residuals using the functions below:
pearson_residuals <- function(p, actual) {
  # Standard deviation of the predicted binomial distribution
  std_dev <- sqrt(p * (1 - p))
  
  # Avoid division by zero in case of p values being 0 or 1
  std_dev[std_dev == 0] <- .Machine$double.eps
  
  # Calculate the Pearson residuals
  residuals <- (actual - p) / std_dev
  
  return(residuals)
}

deviance_residuals <- function(p, actual) {
  # Ensure p is within valid range to avoid log(0) issues
  p <- ifelse(p == 0, .Machine$double.eps, ifelse(p == 1, 1 - .Machine$double.eps, p))
  
  # Calculate the deviance residuals
  residuals <- sign(actual - p) * sqrt(-2 * (actual * log(p) + (1 - actual) * log(1 - p)))
  
  return(residuals)
}

What I have found, strangely, is that the residuals from classifier_log_reg$model$residuals do appear to correspond systematically to residuals that I can calculate manually as the simple difference between the predicted and actual values of the dependant variable. Note that I have adjusted both my manual calculations and the residuals outputted by the model object to best illustrate the apparent sigmoid relationship:

#get residuals directly from the model object
residuals <- classifier_log_reg$model$residuals

#####calculate residuals manually

#specify that predictions should be continuous
classifier_log_reg$predict_type <- 'prob'

#get the predictions
predictions <- classifier_log_reg$predict(task, row_ids = 1:100)

#isolate the vector containing the predictions
predictions <- predictions$data$prob %>% as.data.frame() %>% pull(1) 

#subtract predictions from actual values of dependant variable
actual <- data$dependant %>% as.character() %>% as.numeric()
my_resid <-  actual - predictions 


#put the residuals from the model, the manually calculated residuals
#and the actual values into a dataframe.
#I have adjusted them a bit to illustrate the (apparent) sigmoid relationship that 
#emerges after these adjustments.
df <- data.frame(
  x = residuals - (actual * 2) + 1,
  y = (my_resid + 1) / 2,
  actual = actual
)

#plot the relationship between the manually calculated residuals (with adjustment)
#and the residuals straight from the model (with adjustment).
#The curve is completely smooth, but I cannot find the function linking x to y
ggplot(df) + geom_point(aes(x = x, y = y))


As can be seen, there seems to be a sigmoid relationship here. However, I have tried using the nls function to get the parameters of the best fitting sigmoid curve linking x and y...and it doesn't fit well at all! The below is what I tried; I have not pasted the plot that is produced, but suffice to say that it does not show a straight line (which is what I would expect if the relationship between x and y really is sigmoid):
sigmoid <- function(x, L, k, x0) {
  L / (1 + exp(-k * (x - x0)))
}

model <- nls(y ~ sigmoid(x, L, k, x0), 
             data = df, 
             start = list(L = 1, k = 1,  x0 = 1),
             control = nls.control(maxiter = 100))

df$fitted <- predict(model, df)
ggplot(df) + geom_point(aes(x = fitted, y = y))


So what IS the relationship between x and y here? And more to the point, how are the residuals from the mlr3 logistic regression model being calculated under the hood?

Do we need to install mlr3learners package?

Do you understand logistic regression? Are you familiar with the parts of a generalized linear model, particularly the link function?

Probably the same way that the glm command calculates them:
glm1 <- glm(dependant~predictor, family="binomial", data=data)

identical(residuals, glm1$residuals)
# [1] TRUE

And the type of residuals that glm calculates are the "working" residuals, as mentioned in the docs (see ?glm).
That is, working residuals = 
where  are the working responses and  is the linear predictor.
Some useful links:
Understanding glm$residuals and resid(glm)
Calculating working residuals of a Gamma GLM model

OK, and glm calculates residuals as working residuals, i.e.:
residuals <- (dependant - predictions) / (predictions * (1 - predictions))
So this is also how they are calculated in the mlr3 package in my example.
If you explicitly add this formula to your answer, I can accept it.
